# Get user's location and then show direction with one end point as the user's location using GeolocateControl mapbox

Tags: javascript, web, geolocation, mapbox

I am using web (js) api for mapbox.

```js
var geolocate = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
positionOptions: {
enableHighAccuracy: true
},
trackUserLocation: true
})
map.addControl(geolocate);
```

When I `console.log(geolocate)`, I can find lat lng details in some underscore fields (of the object).
Can't find proper way to get lat lng of the user. But I can't access it in the script, because the geolocate button isn't pressed.

When user's location is found, I want to show direction from the user's location to a fixed point on the map. How to achieve this?
Let me know if things are unclear.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the user's current location each time it is updated by using the geolocate control's [`'geolocate'` event](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geolocatecontrol.event:geolocate). For example:

```
geolocate.on('geolocate', function(position) {
  console.log(`latitude: ${position.coords.latitude}, longitude: ${position.coords.longitude}`);
});
```

Once you've retrieved the latitude and longitude as shown above, you can pass these coordinates to the [Mapbox Directions API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/#directions) along with the coordinates of the "fixed point on the map" to generate a route between the user's current location and said fixed point.

Comment: To add to this you can call `geolocate.trigger()` to trigger the location request without the user clicking the button.

Comment: Yes @AndrewHarvey, I found geolocate.trigger() [in documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geolocatecontrol#trigger) but is not my use case.

Comment: I also found `map.on('locationfound', function(e) {}` event but I couldn't use it, it was depreciated I think.
The `geolocate` event worked.